# Responsive Design / Media Queries / CSS

Tags: css, responsive, media

The index.html page seems to be not working proberly - it's not responsive on the smartphone. However the page hand.html works fine. I already played around with the media queries

Anybody knows how I can fix my problem?

https://christine445.github.io/index.html

This is the code of my index-stylesheet.css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
    width: calc(1200px - 1rem);
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* Pushes picture left a bit */
  .col-lg-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    flex-basis: 43%;
    max-width: 43%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-2dot5 {
    margin-left: 20.83333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-1dot5 {
    margin-left: 8.5%;
  }
}
    /* Ending Screen */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:992px) {
  .col-md-offset-4 {
      margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.66666667%;
    flex-basis: 66.66666667%;
    max-width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }


@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .Home .name {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
  .work-thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 280px;
  }
  .global-nav > .container {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .global-nav.-collapse > .container {
    padding: 2px 20px;
  }
  .nav-list {
    text-align:right;
  }
  .nav-list > .link {
    display: block;
    margin: 7px 8px;
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you have a stray `<script>` tag in the `head` of `index.html`(right below the title) which is causing an issue with your meta tags.

Comment: You're so right! Thanks a lot. Now it works, finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did declare a

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But it's inside a `<script>` tag. Please validate your HTML code. To be sure there aren't any errors. https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I do see that https://validator.w3.org/ didn't catch the ```<meta>``` tag inside a ```<script>``` tag and declare it as false. :-) But if you remove the ```<script>``` tag the responsiveness  features should return. - It's in line 30. (HTML output)

Comment: Yeah, it works :) So good! Thanks a lot, Arno. And thanks for the validator link! Did not know of it before. Have a nice day